# Как прописать класс у ссылки, если она выводится через PHP?

Tags: php, html

У меня есть код, где через цикл выходит список. У каждой строки этого списка есть по две кнопки. Я пытаюсь прописать к ним классы, чтобы изменить стили, но не получается, так как они прописаны в PHP. Как быть?

```
    <? foreach ($articles as $items): ?>
    <div class="art">
        <h3><?=$items['head'];?></h3>
        <div class="buttons">
            <? echo "<a href='?del={$items['id']}'>Удалить</a>"?> 
            <? echo "<a href='?red={$items['id']}'>Редактировать</a>"?> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Во-первых, всё получается. Во-вторых, НЕ НАДО выводить ссылки в РНР. Ссфлки надо выводить в хтмл. А в РНР выводить только переменные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<? foreach ($articles as $items): ?>
   <div class="art">
       <h3><?=$items['head'];?></h3>
       <div class="buttons">
           <? echo "<a class='xxx' href='?del={$items['id']}'>Удалить</a>"?> 
           <? echo "<a class='yyy' href='?red={$items['id']}'>Редактировать</a>"?> 
       </div>
   </div>
   <? endforeach; ?>
```

Вместо xxx и yyy названия классов.

Comment: Странно, у меня ругалось на такую запись.

Comment: @ДмитрийАндреевич Скорее всего потому что вы пытались брать название класса в двойные кавычки, что без экранирования ломает синтаксис

Comment: Да, именно так я и делал. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Сказано же **не надо выводить хтмл через РНР**

Comment: Почему не надо? Предложите в таком случае альтернативный вариант.

Comment: Выше по коду используется этот __альтернативный вариант__, но нет, мы не догадаемся: `<a class="xxx" href="?del=<?=$items['id']?>">Удалить</a>`